# How to run sets of queries in oracle database. if among queries any get fail must be rollback?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, acid

I know this question might be duplicated even though, I am raised the same kind question because mine requirement is different and new to **ORACLE** Database.

Basically, I am having four queries with different tables.

**Query 1:  Table name: users**

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id,user_name,acc_is_active,full_name,email,description,us_report_role,us_is_system,us_is_active)
  VALUES ('aaaaaa',' araut_xxxxxxxx’','Y', ‘Ram G DON’, ‘example@gmail.com’,‘Staff_ID','0','N','Y')
```

**Query 2: Table Name: sequences**

```
update sequences set SQ_SEQ_VALUE='aaaaaa' where SQ_SEQ_NAME='USER_SEQ'
```

**Query 3: Table Name: users_auth_data**

```
 INSERT into users_auth_data (UAD_USER_ID,UAD_KEY,UAD_VALUE) VALUES ('aaaaaa','LDAP_SERVER_ID','-1')
```

**Query 4: Table : users_auth_data**

```
INSERT into users_auth_data (UAD_USER_ID,UAD_KEY,UAD_VALUE) VALUES ('aaaaaa','LDAP_USER_DN','CN=Staff_ID,OU=ExamplePeople,DC=InfoDir,DC=DEV,DC=EXAMPLE')
```

these are four queries I need to run sequentially. if among these any queries get failed then We have to **rollback** the all changes. if all queries runs successfully then will commit all queries changes.

In order to achieve above scenario which approach , we need to follow and how?

If someone help me with solution then it could be great help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rollback in PLSQL Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234347/rollback-in-plsql-exception) See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921477/make-a-pl-sql-stored-procedure-roll-back-all-changes-when-an-exception-occurs/33921900

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for, is a Transaction.

One way to do this via a Pl/Sql block using exceptions.
Ensure that you set

> autocommit off;

```
Declare 
<declare your variables>

Begin
<your queries>
commit; --This will commit the changes if all queries run fine

Exception
WHEN OTHERS THEN

rollback; --This will rollback the changes if there are any exceptions caught.


end;
```

There is one more way to accomplish this which is using save points.
This is better described in the below link :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_transactions.htm